# Free energy along a reaction coordinate

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I've come into this issue when trying to understand biased sampling methods, in particular, umbrella sampling, but I think the question is more general.

A recurring argument is that, along a reaction coordinate $s$ the free energy can be calculated as $A(s) = kT \ln P(s)$, where $P(s)$ is the probability of the reaction coordinate having the value $s$. See, for example [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Molecular_Simulation/Umbrella_Sampling).

I'm having trouble understanding the above relation. Assuming a system with discrete microstates, I would write the free energy of the system as $A_{full} = -kT \ln Z$ with $Z = \sum_i \exp(-E_i/kT)$.
 The probability of $s$ can be written as $P(s) =  Z_s / Z$ where $Z_s = \sum_{s_i} \exp(-E_{s_i}/kT)$. Here the summation goes through the states $s_i$ compatible with $s$.

The free energy at fixed $s$ is then $A(s) = -kT \ln Z_s$. If I go by the previous expression, however, I get $A(s) = kT \ln P(s) = kT \ln Z_s - kT \ln Z$. The sign thus doesn't match and there is an extra $A_{full}=-kT \ln Z$ term. Am I missing something, doing something wrong or $A(s)$ is supposed to be, in fact the free energy difference compared to the full system? If the latter, why is the sign reversed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you. The material in the [link you gave](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Molecular_Simulation/Umbrella_Sampling) seems to be presented in a confusing way. In almost all the standard treatments that I have seen, the free energy as a function of reaction coordinate is defined
$$
A(s) = -k_BT\ln P(s)
$$
and $P(s)$ may be expressed as a ratio of constrained and unconstrained partition functions
$$
P(s) = \bigl\langle \delta(s-s(q))\bigr\rangle =
\frac{\int dq \, \delta(s-s(q)) \exp(-E(q)/k_BT)}{\int dq \, \exp(-E(q)/k_BT)} = \frac{Z(s)}{Z} .
$$
Here, by $q$ I just mean all the coordinates of particles in the system, and $s(q)$ is the reaction coordinate expressed as a function of these coordinates; $\delta(\ldots)$ is the Dirac delta function. This is a very similar formula to yours, just written for a continuum of variables rather than a sum over states.

When you take logs you get
$$
-k_BT \ln P(s) = -k_BT \ln Z(s) + k_BT\ln Z = A(s) - A_\text{full}
$$
The free energy $A_\text{full}$ is just a constant here; we are mainly interested in $A(s)$. Higher probability density $P(s)$ is associated with lower free energy $A(s)$.

I'm not sure why they write it the way they do. It may be a simple mistake. Some confusion can get introduced when a "biasing potential" is introduced to "cancel out" the natural variation of $P(s)$, and produce a biased distribution $P'(s)$ which is flatter. Maybe that's the reason.

---

EDIT following OP comment.

The delta function turns the integral in the numerator into an integration over the "shell" in configuration space (or phase space) which satisfies the constraint $s(q)=s$, where $s$ is the argument of the function $P(s)$. The result is a probability density (per unit $s$). Afterwards, if you integrate $P(s)$ with respect to $s$, you will get $1$: it is normalized, by construction.

If you prefer, you can replace the delta function by a narrow rectangle function of width $\delta s$, and height $1/\delta s$. This enables you to make the connection with a probability histogram, tabulated in fixed-width bins, as one does in an actual simulation. The right-hand side then becomes the probability of finding the system with $s$ in a narrow range $s\ldots s+\delta s$ (divided by a factor of $1/\delta s$), rather than a probability density.  Some care is needed with this factor of $1/\delta s$, but the calculation is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, this was useful. Although not part of the original question and more related to probabilities, can you please explain this in a bit more detail: $P(s) = \bigl\langle \delta(s-s(q))\bigr\rangle$ ? For the second part of that equation, I see that the Dirac delta gathers the exponentials that belong to a certain $s$ value, but I'm a bit confused on the densities within the domain where $\delta$ is not $0$. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried to clarify this aspect by editing my answer: is this what was causing the confusion? If not, please say, and I will try to explain.